# Show a tooltip when we hover over each cell of dropdown options of a column in Aggrid React

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, tablecellrenderer

I have a scenario where the tooltip works perfect for **each cell** (table cell) of a dropdown column in Aggrid React table. I have used tooltipcomponent and tooltipComponentParams to get this working.
Now I want to also achieve same tooltip when user **hovers over the dropdown options**(popup options) of that column. Is there a way we can use cellRenderer to achieve this, how can we know what is current value that is hovered by user in dropdown and how can we further link existing tooltipcomponent to achieve this? Currently, I am using cellRenderer as agRichSelectCellEditor.